# Docker with nodejs doesn't start container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile, very simple

`FROM node:8.12.0-alpine
 EXPOSE 3000
 CMD [ "node" ]`

I run

```
docker build -t node_alpine .
```

and

```
docker run -p 80:3000 node_alpine
```

but the container doesn't start.
when I run

```
docker ps
```

I can't see anythings. Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you just run `node` with no arguments, it will read a program from its standard input, and if there is nothing there, it will promptly exit.  If you run `docker ps -a` you should see the exited container.

I'd recommend setting up an ordinary Javascript development environment on your host.  Once you have your application working, write a Dockerfile that `COPY` your (built) application into an image, and then use a `CMD` to run that.

The Dockerfile you've shown doesn't really do anything.  If you do provide Node with a standard input you'll probably get the interactive prompt

```
docker run --rm -it node:8.12.0-alpine node
```

but that's a pretty roundabout way to get a language interpreter REPL; just install Node directly on your host and use that for development.